# Hash of a hash of a hash

Tags: bash, cryptography

If I shasum a file and pipe that to another file indefinitely (stripping out the file name), will I ever see the same shasum?

```
echo "3" > testfile
while true; do
  shasum testfile > testfile
  cat testfile
done
```

Comment: Test it with your script.

Comment: Depends on the definition of "ever". In theory, there's a limited number of hashes, so they have to repeat at some point. However, exhausting that space may take much, much longer than the Universe exists.

Comment: Are you asking for a fixpoint, ie. whether there's an x such that `shasum(x) = x`?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, `shasum testfile > testfile` is simply illegal. `shasum` is a streaming operation, and you are prematurely truncate the file.

Comment: As the hash has a constant bit-length (160 in your case), there are "only" 2^160 different values (about 1.462e48, or 1462 billions of billions of billions of billions of billions). So, yes, you will definitely see a hash that you've seen before. Be patient and keep trying: if you use a million computers and if they all compute one million hashes per second, because of the birthday paradox (assuming it applies, which is not guaranteed with your recursive scheme), you should see the first duplicate after about 40000 years.

Comment: @4ae1e1 It's not illegal, but it's certainly of no use.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet One million hashes a second? Why would you use a Zilog Z80?

Comment: Yes, for instance, take a look at [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25246/1172). However, since you would only expect one at about 2^80 hashes (birthday problem), you would never ever reach it. There have been distributed attacks on SHA-1, but they made use of cryptographic weaknesses of SHA-1, bringing down the complexity to about 2^63 to 2^69, which still was too high to actually find a so called *collision*. Note that you would also have to store the hashes to be able to compare them, so the memory is as big an issue as the time required to do the hashing.

Comment: Quick rule of thumb, 2^80 is about 10^(80 / 10 * 3) = 10^24, so that's about 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 give or take a few [yotta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(numbers)#1024)-hashes (or quadrillion in the long scale).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: The most powerful bitcoin miners are hashing at about 1 tera-hash per second. And it is SHA-256, not SHA-1. So, a machine that hashes at 1 MH/s is rather reasonable. Basing it on Z80 would probably be challenging, however. Parts are difficult to find these days. More seriously, if we were putting as much effort in finding SHA-1 collisions as we put in bitcoin mining, we would probably succeed in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @Renauld Single threaded, non-optimized Java takes about 0.42 on my laptop for a million hashes (this includes garbage collection). As for the miner: If you have a million machines running for a million seconds you would probably get a collision somewhere along the line. But you also need to store the hashes and link them together. And you need to think of a way to parallelize the problem of course.